# How to restrict a local user to a jail directory in linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kali-linux, users, account-restrictions

I have searched on google for restrict a user to a specific directory but mostly appeared about ssh user, ftp user and etc that not local user.

How do we do that for local user?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Firejail](https://firejail.wordpress.com/) for this purpose, `apt install firejail`.

Running `firejail --private=~/OnlyAccessibleDir` will allow access only to `~/OnlyAccessibleDir` directory.

Comment: Thank you, but can we do that with chroot command?

Comment: Yes, you can use `firejail` in conjuction with `chroot`. Check the documentation, https://firejail.wordpress.com/documentation-2/basic-usage/#chroot